# Editing registry key to force shutdown from a remote system

Tags: windows, remote-access, shutdown

I have a little network of a couple of machines at home, and I need to shutdown them at a certain hour.
I found out that Windows 7 from Pro upwards offers a graphical Security Policies editor, where it's possible to allow the remote shutdown, but apart from mine, the other PCs have just Home Premium, which doesn't have the editor.
I found out that the key is editable without the need of the editor, but how, and where do I find it? 
Or, are there any other ways? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean the "Local Security Policy" administrative tool?  I thought that was available on all versions of Windows 7, though I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never done what you are trying to do in regards to remote shutdown, but here is some information that may be useful:

Are you using the group policy editor for Windows 7 Pro? I believe that's gpedit.msc, right? Back in the day it used to be that you could use regmon (a Sysinternals program) to monitor registry keys that are changed, but it looks like Microsoft bought out Sysinternals and then retired Regmon. However, I believe they moved the functionality to Process Explorer (edit: turns out it's Process Monitor):

Monitor: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Explorer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

On your Windows 7 Pro machine run process monitor and set it up to monitor registry changes for gpedit.msc. Then change the setting using the program. Once you have the key you can document it or export it using regedit. I'm not sure how you plan on changing the registry key remotely, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, thanks to your answer I was able to find the which key was changed (The registry monitor function has moved to Process Monitor, not Explorer though!).
Still, I have a couple of issues. While with gpedit I'm able to access and edit that key, through the Registry Editor I can go further in the SECURITY folder. Here's a pic with the registry key found with Process Monitor and the Registry Editor. http://puu.sh/c06X7/99b4b2340e.jpg

Comment: That's great, I wasn't sure my advice would help you at all. Doing a Google search this pulled up: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows2000/RegistryTips/RegistryTools/HowtobreakintoregistrytoexploreHKLMSAMandHKLMSECURITYkeys.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thanks, it worked like a charm and I was able to add the key!

Comment: So what was the registry key that allowed remote shutdown? I'm on Windows 10 Home and do not have the "Local users and Groups" policy editor, and I'd like to enable "Force shutdown from a remote system" some other way.